# Pullback of Euclidean metric under spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I came across the following problem when I was reading a paper. Let $\Omega=B_2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, which is the ball of radius 2 centered at origin. Map $F:B_2\backslash \{0\}\to B_2\backslash B_1$ is given via
$$
F(x)=(1+\frac{|x|}{2})\frac{x}{|x|}
$$

Now under spherical coordinates $(r,\phi,\theta)$, this $F$ becomes $F:(r,\phi,\theta)\mapsto(\frac{1}{2}r+1,\phi,\theta)$. Then since the metric $g$ is of the form
$$g = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 \sin^2 \phi
\end{pmatrix}$$

I have $$F_{\ast}g=DF^TgDF=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0\\
0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 \sin^2 \phi
\end{pmatrix}$$

However from the paper it seems that the final result is not true. So what is going wrong here when I tried to compute $F_{\ast}g$ ? Thank you in advance!